# Combining obeylines and obeyspaces

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, tabbing

The combination of  `\obeyspaces` and `\obeylines` does not seem to work. In particular, spaces are not obeyed at the beginning of a line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\obeyspaces
\begin{obeylines}
(?:
    ($f()$ 2)
    (g()
       (++ a)
       (-- a)
       (- ($\sin()$ $c$))
    )
    (+ 10 h())
)
\end{obeylines}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Sorry to ask, is this any intend to use `\obeyspaces and obeylines`? As by default `verbatim` environment available for this task...

Comment: @MadyYuvi verbatim would not produce the intended output for $c$

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In that case, generally I'm using `alltt2` or `fancyvrb`...

Comment: In Lisp there must never be a lone `)` on a line. In most (if not all) Lisp coding styles the `)` go at the end of line.

Comment: This particular indentation is meant to show that the list notation is nothing but a textual representation of the tree structure that represents the expression ` f(2) ? g(++a,--b,-sin(c)) : 10+h()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`\obeyspaces` makes a space `\space` but that doesn't stop it being discarded in vertical mode, and obeylines makes every line a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{obeylines}\obeyspaces\def {\mbox{\space}}%
(?:
    ($f()$ 2)
    (g()
       (++ a)
       (-- a)
       (- ($\sin()$ $c$))
    )
    (+ 10 h())
)
\end{obeylines}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will fail if it includes display mode math. IMHO you need to add `everymath`...

Comment: Would it not be better to define the space as ``\leavevmode\space``, since iirc ``\leavevmode`` does nothing in horizontal or math mode ?

Comment: Also, for people trying to use this for defining an environment, you need to change the catcode of the space at the point of the environment definition, else TeX will complain about ``\def`` being followed by a space.

```
\catcode`\ =\active%
\NewDocumentEnvironment{...}%
\catcode`\ =10
```

Comment: @ysalmon well that depends; I assume at the time I was assuming space should make a space in math eg if it was `$\sin( )$`  just `\leavemode` wouldn't be enough

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `listings`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
language=Lisp,
mathescape=true,
columns=fullflexible,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
]
(?:
  ($f()$ 2)
  (g()
    (++ a)
    (-- a)
    (- ($\sin()$ $c$)))
  (+ 10 h()))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, using the `tabbing` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
(\texttt{?:}\=\\
   \> ($f()$~2)\\
   \> ($g()$\=\\
    \> \> (\texttt{++} \=$a$)\\
     \> \> (\texttt{--} \>$b$)\\
      \> \> (\texttt{-}\=\\
      \> \> \> ($\sin()$~$c$)\\
      \>\>)\\
    \>)\\
    \> (+\\
    \>\>10 \\
      \>\>(\\
      \>\>\>$h()$\\
         \>\>)\\
    \>)\\
)
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]